# Axis-Aligned Line Intersects Triangle

Tags: c++, graphics, computational-geometry

How would I go about getting the intersections of a "vertical" line which only has x, y coordinates that is parallel with the z-axis and a triangle of points v0, v1, v2?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Since the Z is constant along your line, you can ignore the Z value of your points. Thus your problem is equivalent to check if the point (x,y) (the line) is inside the triangle v0,v1,v2, taking only their (x,y) values.

Checking if a point is inside a triangle should be quite easy...

Comment: That's all good and well but then I want the intersection point in 3D space.

Comment: You can use the triangle's vertices to determine the plane equation of the triangle, plug in the x and y, and solve for z.

Answer (score 0):

There is a paper, describing a method to solve this problem using barycentric coordinates: [Moller, Trumbore - Fast, Minimum Storage Ray/Triangle Intersection](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~gfx/Courses/2003/ImageSynthesis/papers/Acceleration/Fast%20MinimumStorage%20RayTriangle%20Intersection.pdf). They also have implementation in C.

Also, this algorithm is a foundation of almost all ray-tracing algorithms, so I think you can find its good implementation in the computer graphics area.